# assert error when installing virtualenv with different python

Tags: python, virtualenv

My server has Python2.5 I wanna be jump to newest Python (2.7.x in my case). I compiled python from source, I downloaded newest virtualenv (1.5.1).

Now basically what im trying to do:

```
./packages/virtualenv/virtualenv.py --python=packages/Python-2.7/python env/
```

Typing:

```
./packages/virtualenv/virtualenv.py
```

Provides:

```
1.5.1
```

While Typing:

```
packages/Python-2.7/python
```

Provides:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Nov 21 2010, 23:19:15) 
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
(cut help mesage)
>>>
```

However runing virutalenv results in:

AssertionError: Filename /packages/Python-2.7/Lib/os.py does not start with any of these prefixes: ['/usr/local']

Whatever it means and whatever I am or I am not doing wrong.

P.S.
While building env + python I based at question: [How do I work around this problem creating a virtualenv environment with a custom-build Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278028/how-do-i-work-around-this-problem-creating-a-virtualenv-environment-with-a-custom)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

After reading and messing with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278028/how-do-i-work-around-this-problem-creating-a-virtualenv-environment-with-a-custom).

I found that this error might be related with lack of `--prefix` while runing `./configure` for python. So I've run `./configure --prefix=/Path/To/Where/I/Want/Python/After/Compilation/` (in my case `$HOME/packages/Python-2.7`), then I've typed `make`, then `make install` (without using `sudo` - so python was safely put into where I told it to be as current user not *root*). After that virtualenv initiation did not crash with `AssertionError` and everything worked like a charm.

Hope that this question answered by author will eventually help someone. :)

Comment: I am having this problem on Windows 7, where there is no ./configure used.

Comment: On Windows, I fixed the problem w/ a fresh install - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688709/virtualenv-on-windows-7-returns-assertionerror/10078890#10078890

Comment: // , Can you compile `Python` with a relative `--prefix` argument? That is to say, will an relative paths given via `--prefix` remain relative if the compiled `Python` gets moved?

Comment: This worked for me (on Ubuntu), only when I realised that the Path/To/Python cannot be the same as the directory where you unzipped the tar.gz.

Comment: This presumes that you've done the build and installation yourself, right? As opposed to using something like pip to install virtualenv...

Answer (score 19):

I don't have enough rep to add this as a comment and this question is 3 years old, but this might be useful to someone.  In Windows, you have to path out to **python.exe**, but it seems that in Linux/OS X you just path to the folder. Example:

**Windows:**

```
virtualenv -p <PATH TO PYTHON.EXE> venv
```

Creates a virtual environment in subfolder "venv" in current directory.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to add comment. [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3865600/mike) answer save my day. I'm using windows.

I was getting the error :

```
AssertionError: Filename C:\Python35\Lib\os.py does not start with any of these prefixes: ['c:\\python35', 'c:\\python35']
```

I had to run this-

```
virtualenv -p C:\Python35\python.exe venv
```

also need to run this from a cmd opened as Administrator. Otherwise getting the error

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Someone with enough reps to comment please add this to [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3865600/mike) answer as a comment. I'll then clear mine.