# Visual Studio PyTools Create Virtual Environment Fail

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am trying to create a Virtual Environment using PyTools for Visual Studio 2013. I've manually installed Python before installing Visual Studio 2013 and PyTools, and it functions correctly.

When I try to create a virtual environment through PyTools I get the following error:

AssertionError: Filename c:\Python27\Lib\os.py does not start with any of these prefixes: ['C:\Python27']

C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Lib are in my PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 2):

The assert error was caused because maybe you don't have a PYTHONPATH environment variable setup.

The socket error was caused because there is no included the PythonXX\DLLs folder.

The full PYTHONPATH environment variable should look follows:

> PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs

Here is a full post of that topic [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688709/virtualenv-on-windows-7-returns-assertionerror)