# virtualenv on cygwin returns AssertionError

Tags: cygwin, virtualenv

When I was trying to create a virtual Env on Cygwin by:

```
$virtualenv venv
```

However, it returns error:

```
AssertionError: Filename C:\Python367\Lib\os.py does not start with any of these prefixes: ['C:\\python367', 'C:\\python367']
```

I tried all the solutions under this problem [virtualenv on windows 7 returns AssertionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688709/virtualenv-on-windows-7-returns-assertionerror), but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

After I seek help from other people, I get the root cause:

I was using the python and virtualenv which installed in my windows system, so thus cased the error I put in my question.

```
$ which python
/cygdrive/c/Python367/python <== the python I'm using there is installed in my windows system
```

The solution is, install the python and virtualenv on Cygwin, and then create the virtualenv by the same command. After that you can see the python path is under:

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3 

$ pip3 install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
```

This works for me!