# How to install ipdb with Anaconda on Windows?

Tags: windows, ipython, anaconda, ipdb

I already have Python 2.7 installed but I wanted to try [IPython](http://ipython.org/) so I installed IPython via [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) as recommended on the ipython website (although not sure what the pros/cons of doing this are).  Now I would like to use [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) debugger.  I guess I need to make sure it installs underneath the Anaconda version of python rather than the normal python.

How do I install this?  In general if I want to install some arbitrary python module under Anaconda how do I do this?

Comment: If the package is in the Anaconda repos, you can install it with the `conda` package manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I think in the case of ipdb it's already installed with Anaconda.  But in general it appears you can just install stuff via either pip or easy_install as necessary.  The key that I was missing is to make sure you are using the pip/easy_install that comes with Anaconda (which are .bat files in the Scripts directory) rather than the system Python's pip/easy_install.  So:

`Anaconda\Scripts\easy_install somepackage`

This will install somepackage in `Anaconda\lib\site-packages\` and not in the system python.  This appears to work and I can now import somepackage from my anaconda python.  This seems to work.  It wasn't clear to me from reading Anaconda documentation if everything needed to be in a conda package or not.

This answer seems to support this idea: [Installing Anaconda into a Virtual Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164151/155268)

Comment: For some reason `ipdb` is not in the conda archives (for windows at least).  As `User` says, using `pip` is the correct way and Conda is fine with mixing it with other installers:  "If the package is not available, you can install it by the usual means, e.g. pip," ([Anaconda FAQ](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html))

Comment: doesn't seem to be there for linux either

Comment: on a linux miniconda2 system, I did cd ~/miniconda2/bin -> easy_install pdb and it installed to ~/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipdb-0.9.0-py2.7.egg and idb popped up in the miniconda2/bin dir. This all looks about right to me

Answer (score 2):

Generally the first thing to check is whether someone else has already built it for your version of python and uploaded it to anaconda.org:

```
anaconda search -t conda ipdb
```

then find a repository with ipdb built for your OS, and try

```
conda install -c <repository> ipdb
```

e.g. `conda install -c conda-forge ipdb`

You might need to try a few different ones to find one built for your version of python. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-client/issues/281) to make this easier.

If that doesn't work, then `pip install ipdb` will