# Tell the shell to use a certain python.exe

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda

In my command shell (cmd) I try to convert an .ui file to a .py file via

```
pyuic4 C:\Test\gui.ui > C:\Test\gui.py
```

But it says:

```
The command C:\Python27\python is either typed wrong or could not been found
```

I am using the Anaconda distribution which is placed under AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda and there is a python.exe.

Changing the directory does not work.
How can I compile my .ui-file?

Comment: you can open the python file in the specified directory by giving the complete path name

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727171/installing-anaconda-into-a-virtual-environment?rq=1)

Comment: You mean like `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python.exe pyuic4 C:\Test\gui.ui > C:\Test\gui.py`? This says it does not know `pyuic4`

Answer (score 0):

Use OSGeo4W shell instead of cmd, it can easily convert the .ui file to .py

Run the following command in OSGeo4W shell:

```
C:\path\to\my\ui\files\>pyuic4 -o ui_form.py form.ui
```

Hope this helps!