# Python - import error when trying to activate a virtual environment, or lauch Spyder

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, spyder, pythonpath

I get an ImportError whenever I try to activate a virtual environment, or when I try to launch Spyder.

When trying to activate a virtual environment:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pauline/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 3, in <module>
from conda.cli import main
ImportError: No module named conda.cli
```

When trying to open spyder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pauline/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 2, in <module>
from spyderlib import start_app
ImportError: No module named spyderlib
```

I tried to find an answer for that but I could mainly find problems occurring after Anaconda was just installed (mine has been installed previously and was working fine up until yesterday).

I have also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825250/after-anaconda-installation-conda-command-fails-with-importerror-no-module-na) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981284/pythonpath-error-when-trying-to-activate-a-virtual-environment) but they did not solve the problem.

The only think I can think of which may have provoked this error is that I changed the interpreter used by Spyder yesterday from the default Anaconda Python interpreter to an interpreter from a virtual environment created with virtualenv. Even then, I could close and restart Spyder with no problems, and the errors started after I rebooted my computer.

[edit] I should add that both Anaconda and my virtual environment use the same version of Python which is Python 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a different python version, whatever packages that you had with anaconda or that you may have installed with `conda install` will not be there on the new version. You need to install them with `pip` or `conda` again.

Comment: They are both using the same Python version which is Python 3.5

Comment: sure, but if you do `which python` the python directory is different, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, if I was doing `which python` from my virtual environment I would have `/home/pauline/mybeautifulvenv/bin/python` while anaconda would use its own... So you mean, I should install everything from anaconda in my virtual environment?

Comment: yep, you should repeat the `conda install` in your virtaulenv. The previous installation is not seen by `mybeautifulvenv`

Comment: So I tried `conda install` from my virtual environment, but I get the same error as when trying to open spyder

Comment: in your question, the python you are trying do to the import, is *not* the virtualenv one, it says `/home/pauline/anaconda3/bin/conda` which is the regular anaconda one. You need to do the conda install on the same enviroment as you do the import. Either open and import on  the virtualenv python `/home/pauline/mybeautifulvenv/bin/python`, or do `conda install` in the non-virtualenv. I think you are mixing the two.

Comment: `conda install` won't work, I get the same error be it when no environment is activated, or when `mybeautifulvenv` is activated or when an unrelated environment is activated. Likewise, activating environments, be it `mybeautifulvenv` or an unrelated one won't work. They all return the same error, which makes it difficult to fix

Comment: that means that the libraries were not install to begin with. You should try with `pip` instead of `conda install`. Can you try that?

Comment: Bingo! It worked. Thanks a lot.Bingo! It worked. Thanks a lot. What I did to fix it is: outside the virtual environment `sudo pip install conda` and `conda install spyder` then from inside the environment `conda install spyder`. Just for my general knowledge do you have an idea of what happened which required conda and spyder to be reinstalled?