# How can I update conda without requiring any permissions?

Tags: python, conda

I'm working on a remote server and connecting to it through ssh via terminal; the installed conda version is 4.4.10, and the latest version is 4.9.2, which prevents me from installing the latest versions of python packages. The issue is that I do not have the permissions to update conda. Is any way to update it without requiring permissions?

```
Warning a newer version of conda exists. <== current version 4.4.10 latest version 4.9.2.
```

Comment: Are You sure `pip` is not enough for Your needs? Also, as far as I see, Conda is perfectly installable "locally", as in in Your home directory without much of additional permissions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727171/installing-anaconda-into-a-virtual-environment

Comment: Ask the sys admin to update - that's their job, that's what they do.

Comment: @merv He said that if it is updated, it would affect all users.

Comment: That is a rather generic response and would be true of any software the admin would install/update. Unlike other software, Conda interacts with an online repository which has rolled out interface changes in the 3+ years since they installed the current version. Maybe try to make it concrete to the admin why not updating negatively impacts all users. Also, you are likely not the only user encountering issues - having others voice complaints to the sys admin can help.

Comment: Can you show an example of "prevents me from installing the latest versions of python packages" - what command do you run and what is the error? Are you trying to update packages in an environment that you created (this is how you should use conda) or in the base environment (this is usually a bad idea)?

Comment: @nekomatic for example installing the latest version of opencv raise a segmentation fault (core dumped) that's because the old conda version, yes I'm updating packages in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [installation guide for conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html) says

> We recommend you install Anaconda for the local user, which does not
> require administrator permissions and is the most robust type of
> installation. You can also install Anaconda system wide, which does
> require administrator permissions.

It sounds as if you have the latter type of installation, but you would be better off with the former.

You'll need to agree how to resolve this with your system administrator.